# Android App Crashes on using setText method

Tags: android-studio

I am putting three files 1.activity_main.xml ,2.MainActivity.java ,3.strings.xml files ....I am a new app developer having many issues with doing simple stuff with android apps

1.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="faizsols.com.test.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:text="@string/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="134dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/but1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
    android:onClick="rep"
    android:id="@+id/but1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2.MainActivity.java

```
    package faizsols.com.test;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.string.text1);
Button rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.string.but1);


public void rep(View view) {
    t1.setText("I am fine");
}
```

}

3.strings.xml

```
    <resources>
<string name="app_name">Test</string>
<string name="text1">hello</string>
<string name="but1">Reply</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: use this `TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);` inside onCreate

Comment: That code won't crash at the `setText()` call. It'll crash at the first `findViewById()` call. Are you sure you've got the details right?

Comment: It might be a silly question but I've spent weeks in disappointment..

Comment: Weeks on this code? Just think about this: how does `findViewById` work if no view exists? There is no view until you call `setContentView` in `onCreate`

Comment: That code, as you have it posted, will crash from the first `findViewById()` call. It's nothing to do with your strings.xml, really, though those aren't valid `View` IDs. You should learn to find and interpret the stack trace. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
package faizsols.com.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // You should initialize in onCreate()
        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Button rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
    }

    public void rep(View view) {
        t1.setText("I am fine");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines inside your onCreate below setContentView

```
TextView t1;
Button rpl;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Changes in MainActivity.class


         package faizsols.com.test;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Button;


        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

          @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
              Button rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);


              rpl .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      t1.setText("I am fine");
                   }
             });   


    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Now it doesn't crash..But another one..It crashes after clicking the button

Comment: my repo isn't 15 yet .. :(

Comment: Mr. Hiren...You've downvoted my answer because I didn't select yours as the accepted one. The reason was that you declared the text view and button inside the onCreate method so I found the currently selected answer as a more correct alternative...

Answer (score 0):

update your `MainActivity` with this code:

```
   package faizsols.com.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView t1;
Button rpl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
}

public void rep(View view) {
    t1.setText("I am fine");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to fetch the id in oncreate() method after the setConteview method called.

```
     package faizsols.com.test;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Button;


        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 TextView t1;
  Button rpl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
  rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
    }




    public void rep(View view) {
        t1.setText("I am fine");
    }
```

Comment: Would the variables show up in the method rep() if they're defined in onCreate()..?

Comment: try the above edited post. It'll run without crash. Thank You happy coding

Answer (score 0):

See those lines:

```
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.string.text1);
Button rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.string.but1);
```

It's wrong. You *need* to write **`R.id`**, not `R.string`.

```
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
Button rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
```

---

Use this:

```
package faizsols.com.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    Button rpl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void rep(View view) {
        t1.setText("I am fine");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is solved as of now, but I would like to add a problem that you might be facing with the recent version of Android Studio. It seems impossible to set text with TextView. As an alternative, I have been using EditText as it is easy to use and can be called and defined in any function (not only OnCreate).

Edit text can be found in the palette option under 'text' under the design layout and its use is very similar to TextView

```
 EditText txt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 txt.setText("This actually works");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's the problem with setting text in a TextView? That's one of the most basic android functions and I don't remember ever being a problem. Also, the EditText allows the user to add text in the view so using that instead of a TexView is not always the desired solution.